# Prevent autotools from setting rpath when compiling my program

Tags: c, autotools, libtool, rpath

I'm working on an example autotools project which builds a shared library and a program. The program should link to the shared library. But when I build the program libtool will set the `rpath` like this:

```
RPATH=/usr/local/lib
```

which I don't want.

According to the Debian Wiki libtool isn't supposed to set the `rpath` when the library is in the default search path ([libtool's role](https://wiki.debian.org/RpathIssue#libtool.27s_role)).

According to this [site](http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_debian.org/Documentation/elf/node16.html) `/usr/local/lib` should be in the default search path of the linker.

The library and the program are build by the same autotools project, so the library is not installed when the program is build.

Does anybody have an idea why libtool sets the `rpath` anyway?

Comment: Basically, you want to know how to override the RPATH.  I'll assume you'll take care of detection of the distro platform.

Answer (score 0):

- with readelf readelf -d libfftw3_mpi.so you can check if your lib contains such a attribute in the dynamic section.
- with export LD_DEBUG=libs you can debug the search path used to find your libs
- with chrpath -r  the rpath can be changed

As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520976/4379130 by @bonoparte